# Pyspark - name 'when' is not defined

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

Could someone please help me with the below.

```
joinDf = join_df2(df_tgt_device_dim.withColumn("hashvalue", F.sha2(F.concat_ws(",", *valColumns), 256)).alias("target"),
                      df_final.withColumn("hashvalue", F.sha2(F.concat_ws(",", *valColumns), 256)).alias("source"),
                      conditions,
                      "full_outer",
                      keyColumns)

deltaDf = get_active_records(joinDf, common_cols, "Type2")

wind_spc = Window.partitionBy(*keyColumns).orderBy(col("effective_start_ts").desc())

df_device_new = deltaDf.withColumn("Rank", F.row_number().over(wind_spc))
deltaDf_final = df_device_new .filter( col("diff") != 'unchanged_act_records').withColumn("crnt_ind",when(df_device_new .Rank == 1 ,lit('Y'))\
                                                             .when(df_device_new.Rank != 1 ,lit('N'))).drop("Rank")

deltaDf_final.union(deltaDf.filter(col("diff") == 'unchanged_act_records').withColumn("crnt_ind",lit('N'))).createOrReplaceTempView(f"device_delta")
```

Below is the error.

```
NameError: name 'when' is not defined
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-104590> in <module>
     17 wind_spc = Window.partitionBy(*keyColumns).orderBy(col("effective_start_ts").desc())
     18 df_device_new = deltaDf.withColumn("Rank", F.row_number().over(wind_spc))
---> 19 deltaDf_final = df_device_new .filter( col("diff") != 'unchanged_act_records').withColumn("crnt_ind",when(df_device_new .Rank == 1 ,lit('Y'))\
                                                             .when(df_device_new.Rank != 1 
     21 deltaDf_final.union(deltaDf.filter(col("diff") == 'unchanged_act_records').withColumn("crnt_ind",lit('N'))).createOrReplaceTempView(f"device_delta")

NameError: name 'when' is not defined
```

I have tried F.when, but it did not work.

Could someone please assist thank you.

Comment: Did you imported it? [Ref](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.when.html)

Comment: `("crnt_ind",when` should be `("crnt_ind").when`

Comment: no there's no method `when` of dataframes. you're thinking of `where`. the problem is indeed that `when` has not been imported. `from pyspark.sql.functions import when`

Comment: Thank you, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.otherwise` instead of `.when` after first `.when`

```py
df_device_new = deltaDf.withColumn("Rank", F.row_number().over(wind_spc))
deltaDf_final = df_device_new .filter( col("diff") != 'unchanged_act_records').withColumn("crnt_ind",when(df_device_new .Rank == 1 ,lit('Y'))\
                                                             .otherwise(df_device_new.Rank != 1 ,lit('N'))).drop("Rank")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).